# Filter and display data with asp mvc partial views and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Thanks for help before. I'll appreciate it ;)

I've been googling to answer this problem but I didn't find the right answer yet.

I've been trying to filter my results (records) by using dropdown as the filter and using jquery in ASP MVC (Just in my case).

[the image for the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXvPD.png)

(Urutkan berdasarkan means Filter by. And Terbaru means Newest.)

The dropdown enables you to sort the content by Date, Popular, and Alphabet.
How can I filter it by jquery with dropdown?

Here's the view:

```
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12  hide-on-small-only hide-on-med-only" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #9e9e9e;">
                <div class="col l9">
                    <span class="inline">
                        <span class="left-align grey-text text-darken-3 left" style="font-size: 1.7rem;">Artikel Medis</span>
                        <span class="right-align right" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                            <label class="black-text">Urutkan Berdasarkan:</label>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col l3 right left-align select-web-news" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                    @Html.DropDownList("FilterDropdown")
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12 left">
                <ul class="ul-news" id="target">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ArticleClient)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_News.cshtml", item)
                    }
                </ul>
                <div class="pager">
                    @Html.Pager(Model.ArticleClient.PageSize, Model.ArticleClient.PageNumber, Model.ArticleClient.TotalItemCount)
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#FilterDropdown").change(function () {
        var filterSelected = $("select option:selected").first().text();
        $.get('@Url.Action("~/Views/Shared/_News.cshtml")', { id: newsFilter }, function (data) {
            $("#target").html.data;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

can anyone help me to solve and for sorting this with jquery or javascript?

fell free for using fiddle.

If the view in my ASP MVC is not understandable. Let's pretending the view would be like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Sort by Name</option>
  <option value="1">Sort by Date</option>
  <option value="2">Sort by Popular</option>
</select>
<ul class="listitems">
    <li data-position="1">
      <div class="name">Item 1</div>
      <div class="date">11/01/2000</div>
      <div class="popular">2</div>
    </li>
    <li data-position="2">
      <div class="name">Item 2</div>
      <div class="date">11/01/2001</div>
      <div class="popular">3</div>
    </li>
    <li data-position="3">
      <div class="name">Item 3</div>
      <div class="date">11/01/2002</div>
      <div class="popular">4</div>
    </li>
    <li data-position="4">
      <div class="name">Item 4</div>
      <div class="date">11/01/2003</div>
      <div class="popular">5</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Oia, if my ASP MVC code is not appropriate, feel free to give me the suggestion ;)
Thanks for guidance :)

Comment: So what problems are you having. What is not working?

Comment: Can I change my question? I want to make this simple @StephenMuecke

Comment: You can edit your question :) (you have shown far too much irrelevant code anyway)

Comment: lol, sorry because I am new in stackoverflow too :D @StephenMuecke Thanks for help master!!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place where people will do the work for you. You have not even tried to attempt a solution. Learn jQuery, try it out. If it's still not working then post what you have tried.

Comment: Actually I've tried. But the code is not working. for example like here http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Yke6M/ @garethb

Comment: Then change you question. Specify what you are trying to accomplish in the fiddle and whats not working. And post a link to the fiddle. Also post the html and javascript from the fiddle in the question. Remove your other code.

Comment: I've edited my question :) thanks for suggestion (y) @garethb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to change the '@Url.Action("~/Views/Shared/_News.cshtml")' of get request. The get request will be

```
 $.get('@Url.Action("/ControllerName/ActionName")',        
         { id: newsFilter },        
         function (data) {
            $("#target").html.data;
        });
```

The method of Controller may be looks like

```
public ActionResult FilteredResult(int newsFilter)        
{

//Do your work and pass the model to the view

return View("YourFilteredViewName",filderedModelData);

}
```

So by doing this you will get filtered view and able to parse the "#target" ul of the Dom.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :)